# How can i use google creds json and google map Geocoding API in python instead of api key to get lat long from address

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use geocode api to get lat long from a address given . In most example they are using api key . I have downloaded google creds and want to use it. I have enabled the api from console.

is there any way to use google creds json

```
import os
import sys
def credentials_gc():
    filename = get_latest()
    print (filename)
        
    
    
    path_to_credentials = r'C:\Users\JSON_file\MyFirstProject-1f059a7.json'
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=path_to_credentials
    return os.environ


os.environ = credentials_gc()
     
gmaps = googlemaps.credentials() # not working
gmaps = googlemaps.Client() 



    
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'

params = {
            'address': 'oshiwara industerial center goregaon west mumbai',
            'sensor': 'false',
            'region': 'india'
        }

# Do the request and get the response data
req = requests.get(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL, params=params)
res = req.json()

# Use the first result
result = res['results'][0]

geodata = dict()
geodata['lat'] = result['geometry']['location']['lat']
geodata['lng'] = result['geometry']['location']['lng']
geodata['address'] = result['formatted_address']

print('{address}. (lat, lng) = ({lat}, {lng})'.format(**geodata))
```

Comment: Are you using Google App Engine or other Google Cloud products or services? Where will you use the Google credentials?

Comment: Specifically which Google Cloud product?

Comment: google map .. sorry i ment google service . i am using this documentation just want to avoid api key generation since i downloaded the creds. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, only API key is supported by Google Maps Platform as shown in this documentation on [Using API Keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

If you want this feature to be available in future iterations of Google Maps, you could file a feature request through this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker).